# Transpose specific columns using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to transpose below data using python pandas. But I am not getting a proper solution as i want transpose specific columns.

***Input Data Format-***
[image]

***Output Data Format-***
[image]

Comment: It's always better to provide code examples of your data rather than pictures. It help members to recreate the data in their system & test their logic before posting answers…

Comment: Thanks Sachin for the suggestion and your solution is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **melt**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["a","a","a","a"],
                   "Date":["date1","date2","date3","date4"],
                   "H1":[1,1,1,1],
                   "H2":[2,2,2,2],
                   "H3":[3,3,3,3],
                   "H4":[4,4,4,4]})
df1 = pd.melt(df,id_vars =['ID','Date'], value_vars =['H1','H2','H3','H4'])
```

Output of df;

[image]

Output of df1;

[image]